# How to solve this constrained maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming, qcqp

Does anyone have an idea of how to tackle the following maximization problem?

> Maximize the function $ f(x,y,z) = x - y - \alpha z^2 $, $ \alpha > 0 $, under the following constraints:
>
> - **C1:** $ x>0 $, $\:\: y>0 $, $\:\: 0<z<1 $
> - **C2:** $ y - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + c_1x \geq 0 $, $\:\: c_1>0 $
> - **C3:** $ y - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} (c_2 - A z )^2 < 0 $, $\:\: c_2,A>0 $

I would be grateful for any help/suggestions! :)

Comment: What is $\alpha$ ?

Comment: If you keep all the inequality strict, then there is no maximum clearly. $f$ does not have any critical points.

Comment: @Pebeto Thank you!